# Quicksort Hoare's partition

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

```
algorithm quicksort(A, lo, hi) is
    if lo < hi then
        p := partition(A, lo, hi)
        quicksort(A, lo, p)
        quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)

algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
    pivot := A[⌊(hi + lo) / 2⌋]
    i := lo - 1
    j := hi + 1
    loop forever
        do
            i := i + 1
        while A[i] < pivot
        do
            j := j - 1
        while A[j] > pivot
        if i ≥ j then
            return j
        swap A[i] with A[j]
```

I tried to find explicit answers to the following questions in [Quicksort/Hoare_partition_scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) but I could not, although trying out some examples by hand shows that the following would most likely be correct...
My questions are, is it always guaranteed that

- `partition` returns the position of the chosen pivot
- does it matter to return `i` or `j`, or rather would it not be the case that the algorithm stops at  `i==j`
- in the `quicksort` does it matter if the calls are `(lo,p-1) and (p,hi)` vs `(lo,p) and (p+1,hi)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the first question is in the linked article:

> In this scheme, the pivot's final location is not necessarily at the
> index that is returned, as the pivot and elements equal to the pivot
> can end up anywhere within the partition after a partition step.

A simple example is partitioning the array [2,0,1,3,4].

The pivot is 1.
`i` will stop at the 2.
`j` will stop at the 1.
After swapping, the array is [1,0,2,3,4].
`i` will then move to the 2 again.
`j` will move to the 0, and the position of the 0 will be returned.

That example array also answers the second question. After the partition, `j` is 1, and `i` is 2.

To answer the third question, I think all you need to do is swap the 2 and the 3 in the initial array.